Nodemon is not restarting after I save the file. The message "[nodemon] restarting due to changes..." appears, but the server does not restart
enter image description here
Nodemon is not restarting after I save the file. The message "[nodemon] restarting due to changes..." appears, but the server does not restart. I have been facing this issue for a long time. Is there any solution available for this problem? any solution so please tell me?
Package.json file

"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
 }


could you please share the code as well ? the way nodemon is setup ?

HI, welcome. What exactly is the change that doesn't show up? CSS? Other? Also, a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
